# Pagination in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, pagination

So I'm just trying to make a `pagination component` in react. Im currently using `redux` for my state management and using `semantic-ui` for the pagination component.
I have currently made a react component in my `action.jsx` file and have two other functions which one of them is for `data fetching` for my redux state and one other for the declaring the current `active page` value and set the `new target url` for data fetching.

```js
    export class Paginator extends React.Component {


        state = {
            page: [],
            pages: []
          }
          
         handlePage(activePage) {
          let pagenum = activePage;
          let pagestring = pagenum.toString();
          paginationUrl = '/api/v1/products/index/?page=' + pagestring; ----> Pass This Url
        }


        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get("/api/v1/products/index", { withCredentials: true })
              .then(response => {
                  this.setState({
                    page: response.data.page,
                    pages: response.data.pages
                  })
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("Check Login Error", error);
              });
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <Pagination onPageChange={this.handlePage} size='mini' siblingRange="6"
                defaultActivePage={this.state.page}
                totalPages={this.state.pages}
                />
            )
        }
    }


   export function fetchProducts() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsRequest())
        axios
        .get("To Here !")
        .then(response => {
            // response.data is the products
            const products = response.data.products
            dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(products))

        })
        .catch(error => {
            // error.message is the error message
            dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error.message))
        })
    }
    }
```

The question is how am i able to pass the `paginationUrl` to the function below ? (Actually, there is no way i guess !).

Note: I am only able to use `handlePage` in the same component with the pagination component.

Waiting for suggestions, Thx in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the URL to the `fetchProducts` function when dispatching actions on page changes.

```js
handlePage(activePage) {
  const url = `/api/v1/products/index/?page=${activePage}`
  dispatch(fetchProducts(url))
}
```

And update the `fetchProducts` action creator to use the URL.

```js
export function fetchProducts(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsRequest())
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data.products))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error.message))
      })
  }
}
```

---

This is unrelated to the question but I would strongly recommend using [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) to simplify data fetching and synchronization.

Comment: I would only add to this, that fetchProducts should be reused in the componentDidMount call. I would also advice to extract that function to a different file.